# How to get input value from html form in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, input

I want to ask how i can get value of input ONLY ON SUBMIT in Javascript from HTML form when i have many forms with same name on one page.
It's looking like this:

First printed HTML form:

```
<div id="addCommentContainer3">
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm3" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost"/>
<textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Second printed:

```
<div id="addCommentContainer2">
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm2" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost"/>
<textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

And like this there are many more .

I must take the value of `comentonpost` because i need it in my Javascript so when i post comment it wil appear before `addCommentContainer` of the submited form.
And there is the whole Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var name_element = document.getElementById('comentonpost');
var x = name_element.value;

/* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

/* This flag will prevent multiple comment submits: */
var working = false;

/* Listening for the submit event of the form: */
$('#addCommentForm'+x).submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    if(working) return false;

    working = true;
    $('#submit').val('Working..');
    $('span.error').remove();

    /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
    $.post('comment.submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

        working = false;
        $('#submit').val('Submit');


            /* 
            /   If the insert was successful, add the comment
            /   below the last one on the page with a slideDown effect
            /*/

            $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer'+x).slideDown();


    },'json');

});

  });
```

And in this way when i press the Submit button it's working only for the first form printed in the page.
**My question is how i can fix this? How i can make it get the `comentonpost` value only of the submited form not the first printed, is there any better way this script may work?


Thanks in advance!**

Comment: The inputs and textareas have the same id, which is invalid (and the id selector will only get the first one). You have already done it correctly for the `addCommentContainerN` and `addCommentFormN`, so you should be able to fix it yourself :-)

Comment: what is the var `x` in your selector? what is that supposed to do? Isn't it supposed to differentiate the forms from each other?

Comment: looks to me like you are only listening to the submit event on one form.

Comment: @AustinAllover that looks to me too. seems like he had forgotten about the `x` var.

Comment: Yes @MiroMarkarian this is the purpose of var x.

Comment: @AustinAllover so what you suggest?

Comment: @ViolinaMilanova so where do you update the `x` ? have you put the code in a `for` loop?

Comment: You can do something like 

`['1', '2', '3'].map(function (x) {...yourcode...});`

where `yourcode` is the `submit` part with the selector. No need to change anything exctep to wrap it in a map for example.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix thats a good solution instead of `for`...

Comment: So how will look my Javascript in this case I, I just don't get it...

Comment: http://paste2.org/KPtbWLba

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Watch OnSubmit for all forms */
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        /* Show the 'commentonpost' for the submitted form */
        alert($(this).children('#comentonpost').val());
    });
});
```

This works, but you should keep in mind that your document is not valid because you have elements that have the same IDs.  IDs must be unique within a document for it to be valid.

Comment: What do you mean how my IDS must look like ?

Comment: IDs must be unique within a document, read section 7.5.2 in this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html  I am not suggesting you go and change all your IDs.  I am just pointing out that you have an invalid document (you can search the web for why this is a bad idea).  You have to decide what is more important to you: getting it done or have a valid document.

Answer (score 0):

when you use jquery to select an ID, it will return 0 or one elements that match, and it will match the first one it finds. from http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

> Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will
>   return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one
>   DOM element.

whenever you use $("#submit") its parsing through the DOM and finding the first instance of `<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />` and returning that element.  what you really want to do in your to scope your search down.  you know you want the input from the form that was submitted, so you should try

```
$(this).find("#submit")
```

this will start at the form element, and search only elements contained inside the form for the first element with an ID of submit.

**update**

didnt realize your event was only tied to the first form, this whole things needs some work.

you've got a generic form template, and when you've got multiple forms like this, you really shouldnt be giving them all the same ID.  instead, start binding event handlers to classes, and use the dom to store whether a form is 'working' or not as well

http://jsfiddle.net/neKdz/3/

Comment: I don't get it... where i must put this `$(this).find("#submit")` ?

Comment: IDs must be unique document-wide, a scoped search doesn't make much sense (though it works). Please suggest to use classes instead.

Comment: How my Javascript will look @Bergi to work with class?
What i must change ?

Comment: @ViolinaMilanova: Remove the invalid ids, and change your `'#submit'` selectors to something like `'#addCommentForm'+x+' input[type="submit"]'`

Comment: @ragnarok56 In your jsfiddle the java script is not showing. I mean this is not there `$(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer'+x).slideDown();` How this this must be? Thanks a lot man!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/neKdz/4/   I just simulated your post back with a setTimeout and took out anything that wasnt critical to the question. but the jsfiddle i updated has that in there as well. it just references the local `form` variable that was defined above

Comment: The post must appear before `<div id="addCommentContainer">` of the submited post but how it will be? And there is another problem with this jsfiddle - every time when i click on the input text are it's givig new `Here are some results or something`. Is there any way o can copy this code to test it so i can say how it works? Thanks man it's a great help to me. Really I appreciate it!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/neKdz/5/  - updated because events werent setup the right way.  i added comments to explain how things work a bit, you should just be able to copy and paste the js from the left, comment/uncomment out some lines at the bottom relating to the post back parts, rename some classes in the html and try it out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/neKdz/6/ - didnt see the addCommentContainer bit, just added the surrounding div element and changed the selector for where to place the html to use that one

Comment: I think this http://jsfiddle.net/neKdz/5/ will do the work without the div addCommentContainer in this case it's not needed, Am i right?
And still i don't know how to coppy the code from http://jsfiddle.net/neKdz/5/ and test it. Can you please paste it to paste2.org ?

Comment: can you not see the code from jsfiddle? regardless, i coped the html and js code to http://paste2.org/1e8YYIvG

Comment: I have tried the code you give me but it's not working. When i press the Submit button just nothing happens. I don't know why, it seems to work well on jsfiddle.net. In my head tags i have `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/js/comments.js"></script>` in which comments.js is loading the javascript you've writen. Where the problem can be? There you can see how exactly the form code is looking like - http://paste2.org/VILjOeXA

Comment: verify your html is correct.  the submit input should have `class="add-comment-submit"` on it.  you also need to edit the js code, since it only simulates the post, you have to uncomment out some lines at the bottom and comment out the setTimeout stuff.  i think this is basically the limit of how i can help you.

Comment: Here you can see my HTML form http://paste2.org/VILjOeXA Did i wrong somewhere? Here is how my comments.js is looking - http://paste2.org/OsfPZBhb

Comment: use this js instead. you left the setTimeout in there and it wasnt matching all the braces - http://paste2.org/aW0JgMwP

Comment: So the html must look like this- http://paste2.org/KKcJc7Y5 and JS like this - http://paste2.org/FVgjFIPD and it will work? It will print the posted comment which is also sended in comment.submit.php to be inserted in MySQL?

Comment: It's seems this Javascript is not sending POST information to comment.submit.php

Answer (score 0):

You may only need to change this part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

  /* This flag will prevent multiple comment submits: */
  var working = false;

  /* Listening for the submit event on all the forms: */
  $('form[id^=addCommentForm]').on('submit', (function(e) {
    var submitted_form = $(this);
    //etc...
```

Comment: And there will be no problem if the form names are different like `addCommentForm3` or `addCommentForm2` it will work?

Comment: It will work, it means forms with id starting with addCommentForm, although Hugo Paz (@hugo-paz) refactoring is way better.

Comment: Yes but it should add comment on just one not all which starts with addCommentForm.

Comment: You do have a handle to the one form that was submitted in `var submitted_form = $(this);`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-comment-form").submit(function(e){
        var x = $(this).find("#comentonpost").eq(0).val();
        // now you have number x of submitted form and you can do the rest
    }); 
});
```

Edit:

To prevent page reloading because of form submission, add onSubmit="return false;" on form elements, e.g.:

```
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm3" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return false;" >
```

But because of this we have to follow another approach using click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        var x = $(this).parent(".add-comment-form").eq(0).find("#comentonpost").eq(0).val();
        // now you have number x of submitted form and you can do the rest
    }); 
});
```

Combination of click event and cancelling submit event should work. But just for the record (you should already know this, but I can imagine you might have a reason for doing it) using same id on multiple html elements is not a good strategy.

Comment: It's not working. When i press submit it's just refreshin the page but nothing.